# default url access denied - sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, url, alternate-access-mapping, access-denied, url-rewriting

when trying to access the site from the default URL for ex: `http://mysite.site.net` it give an **ACCESS REQUIRED** error even for the system account but when i try to open any site (URL) under this url ex: `http://mysite.site.net/sitepages/home.aspx` it opens perfectly, all the AAM are configured as well as the bindings in IIS. am i missing anything?

any help appreciated.

Comment: could you please give us more details about error? also what are your AAM settings?

Comment: it is not actually an error, when i type http://mysite.site.net it is redirecting to the accessdenied.aspx and in the page "sorry you don't have access to this page" with the page title "Access Required"

AAM:
internal urls:

http://mysite.site.net     default
http://mysite              default